# Auto generating objective-c classes from *.xsd schema file

Tags: c++, objective-c, xsd, xml-parsing

I have XSD schema files that are huge in size.

I need to create classes from these files but doing so manually is not the right way as there are some tools that create classes automatically, for e.g. Microsoft tool "XSD.exe" that converts the files into c++ classes. I wanted to use them in Xcode but I am finding it difficult to port it.

What is a good tool that can generate objcetive-c classes which can be used on iOS?

Thanks in advance,

Amit

Answer (score 1):

If your generated C++ is standards compliant (no platform specific extensions), you can just use the C++.